# Assign attributed text to tooltip in Swift

Tags: swift, tooltip, nsattributedstring

I am trying to make a tooltip with bold text. I figured `NSAttributedString` can be used make a string bold. However tooltip only accepts `string` type. Is there a way to make tooltip with bold font.

Here a sample of what I am trying to achieve(from Xcode):

[image]

Comment: What `tooltip`? Meaning you use a third party lib? Which one?

Comment: @Larme .Default one cocoa.(https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nstoolbaritem/1524627-tooltip)

Comment: You seem to be able to set tie `view`, so you might have a `NSView` with a `NSAttributedString` drawned? Or maybe with a label on it?

Comment: The `view` in that Apple documentation link is in the `See Also` section. It refers to `NSToolbarItem.view` not the `toolTip`'s view.